# How can I make a loop with PyQt4?

Tags: loops, python-3.x, pyqt4, qapplication

I'm trying to make a program that opens a window every 10 seconds and waits for the user to close it, in order to restart counting the next 10 seconds.

I have the following code:

```
class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 300)
    self.setWindowTitle('Probando...')

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
window = Window()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

The big question I have, is how could I make a loop where I can reinstanciate Window every 10 seconds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyQt4 - creating a timer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362340/pyqt4-creating-a-timer)